# How can I make a Self Containing Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an object that is created like so...

```
SomeObject()
```

I then want to be able to access this same object from anywhere by doing something like...

```
var object_instance = SomeObject().GetInstance();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That's not very clear at all, are you asking how to create a function that returns an object ?

Comment: Make it global so you can access from everywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called the **singleton pattern**, here you have how to implement it in Javascript by Addy Osmani.

https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#singletonpatternjavascript

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).